# Locate precisely the area for click in image source

Tags: javascript, html, svg, coordinates, area

I have this image. The user need to click at the location on number 1. How I can do that?

[image]

I used to implement this with such code from a sample of map:

```
<area shape="poly" coords="409,298,409,298,411,292,409,279,409,233,408,233,437,231,446,263,449,267,448,270,448,275,450,285,421,288,420,290,423,294,423,296,420,299,418,297,416,294,414,294,414,298,409,298" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama" title="Alabama">
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how they set the coords?Any better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you can use a circular area. The appropriate coords can be determined with an image editor. `<area shape='circle' coords='80,41,28'>` - That's a centre at 80,41 and a radius of 28px

Comment: Ooo..what type of image editor? Can you give me the name?

Comment: I just used Gimp. It's a manual process - you open the image and inspect it by hand. In the case of SVGs, you _may_ be able to programmatically analyse them in order to automatically create hot-spots.

Comment: Ok thanks @enhzflep for the help.